# Timestamp conversion in Kinesis firehose after record format conversion to Parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have been using [record format conversion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html) in kinesis firehose for converting the files in parquet format in S3 where in the schema that I have is being stored in AWS Glue. I am struggling in an issue where I am unable to configure the timestamp format that should be present when this data will be dumped to S3 bucket.

There is a field in the overall record which is a timestamp field(epoch value in seconds) which is being passed to kinesis and during record format conversion, I have used  OpenX JSON SerDe because it supports epoch value in seconds. After this conversion, the schema that has been picked has field of the type  `glue.schema.TIMESTAMP`. Now, when I use S3 select to query the data in this parquet files, the timestamp value is getting converted to format BigInt, i.e.  `4.5372829208888797985120256e+25`, whereas I need the timestamp in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.